# How to wait for an animator to finish?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

This is probably a simple question but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Basically all I want to do is fade a window before closing it:

```
[[window animator] setAlphaValue:0.0];
[window close];
```

This works fine without the [window close], but when that is included the window seems to close it before the animation finishes (which is obviously not what I want); the same seems to happen for orderOut:, performClose:, etc. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[[window animator] setAlphaValue:0.0];
[window performSelector:@selector(performClose:) withObject:self afterDelay:[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] duration]];
```

Comment: The message to the currentContext should be -animationDuration, not -delay.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using this:

 [window performSelector:@selector(close)
              withObject:nil
              afterDelay:[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] duration]];

Comment: Thanks kperryua and Michael. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old (but still popular) question with obsolete answer.

The right way to wait for animator finished is using special `NSAnimationContext`'s class method with `completionHanler` like this:

```
[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context){
    // Start some animations here.
    [[window animator] setAlphaValue:0.0];
} completionHandler:^{
    // This block will be invoked when all of the animations started above have completed or been cancelled.
    NSLog(@"All done!");
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

Implicit animations triggered through the animator proxy run on wall time. Get the duration from the current NSAnimationContext and perform delay your cleanup/post-animation operations using that interval.