# Deallocating window when animations may be occurring

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit, nswindowcontroller

My `AppDelegate` maintains a list of active window controllers to avoid ARC deallocating them too early. So I have a notification handler like this:

```
- (void) windowWillClose: (NSNotification*) notification {
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(removeWindowControllerInMainThread:)
        withObject: windowController
        waitUntilDone: NO];
}

- (void) removeWindowControllerInMainThread: (id) windowController {
    [windowControllers removeObject: windowController];
}
```

I use the main thread because doing the handling on the notification thread risks deallocating the controller before it's ready.

Now, this works pretty well — except when there are animators currently running. I use animators in some places, through `NSAnimationContext`. I have looked at [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077793/how-to-wait-for-an-animator-to-finish), and the answer just isn't acceptable. Waiting for a while, just to get animation done, is really shoddy and not guaranteed to work; indeed it doesn't. I tried using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`, even with a larger delay than the current animation duration, and it still results in the animator running against nil objects.

What is the preferred way of doing controller cleanup like this? Not use `NSAnimationContext` but using `NSAnimation` instead, which has a `stopAnimation` method?

Answer (score 2):

First, if some of your animations run indefinitely -- or for a very long time -- you're going to have to have a way to stop them.

But for things like implicit animations on views, you could simply use a completion method.

```
  self.animating=YES;
  [NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context){
    [[v animator] setAlphaValue: 1];
} completionHandler:^{
    self.animating=NO;
}];
```

Now, you only need to poll whether your animation is running and, if it's not running, proceed to close your window.

One nice way to do the polling is to set a timer with a fixed delay. If the animation is still running, just reset the timer and wait another interval.

Alternatively, you could send a notificaton  from the completion handler.

Comment: I don't like the idea of polling, but all right. DRY and separation of concerns dictate that this should not be something the window controller should need to care about at all, so for the moment I have packaged this functionality into a window controller base class.

Comment: If you'd rather not poll, send a notification to the controller from the completion handler.  Or, if the animating object knows about the windowController, send it a `willAnimate`` message when the animation starts and a `didAnimate` when the animation ends.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used `NSAnimationContext` (always did this with `NSAnimation`, but mostly for historical reasons). But the typical way I like to managed things similar to this is to create short-lived retain loops.

Mark's answer is exactly the right kind of idea, but the polling is not required. The fact that you reference `self` in the completion handler means that `self` cannot deallocate prior to the completion handler running. It doesn't actually matter whether you ever read `animating`. ARC has to keep you around until the completion block runs because the block made a reference to you.

Another similar technique is to attach yourself to the animation context using `objc_setAssociatedObject`. This will retain you until the completion block runs. In the completion block, remove `self` as an associated object, and then you'll be free to deallocate. The nice thing about that approach is that it doesn't require a bogus extra property like `animating`.

And of course the final, desperate measure that is occasionally appropriate is to create short-lived self-references. For instance:

```
- (void)setImmortal:(BOOL)imortal {
  if (immortal) {
    _immortalReference = self;
  }
  else {
    _immortalReference = nil;
  }
}
```

I'm not advocating this last option. But it's good to know that it exists, and more importantly to know why it works.