# How to use performSelector: afterDelay: after doing animations?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Let me make myself clear. I'm using a series of animations which get triggered by user actions.

Only when I do a performSelector:afterDelay: it doesn't work if done after an animation.

I don't know if this answer would work for me if I was doing OS X development, but it might be a clue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1078216/676822

Could anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Are you aware of UIView animation blocks?

Comment: yes, that's what I'm using

Comment: I'm just wondering why you're using `performSelector:afterDelay:`. Could you post some code?

Comment: it's more complicated than it seems. I can rewrite the code in that manner to make it work but I favor reusing my animation methods

Comment: I need to see your animation methods.

Comment: it's a simple animateWithDuration called with a performSelector:afterDelay. So after I call that I cannot call another simple animation after a delay. Everything in the same view

Comment: Seriously, post your code so we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather, you're trying to perform a series of animations, each with a delay before they begin. So, instead of using `performSelector:afterDelay:` to call the animations, you can nest calls to `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:2.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

     //your first animations

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:2.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

         //your second animations

     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

     }];
}];
```

This method accepts an extra `delay` parameter which sounds like what you're wanting. And since you're second animation is in the first's completion block, the animations will happen in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take some action at the end of the animation, the appropriate code looks like:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.50 animations:^{
    // your changes to animate here
 } completion:^(BOOL completed) {
    // your code after animation here
 }];
```

There's several other variants of animateWithDuration that allow more features of the animation itself.